# How to pass a Model to FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

If a user is authenticated, I want to take him to the "home" page but with a model that contains the user profile, otherwise, I want to post-back the same page with the model errors. Here's what I have done:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index(Login loginViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IUserProfile userProfile = ValidateUser(loginViewModel);

                if (userProfile != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(loginViewModel.UserName, loginViewModel.RememberMe);
                    // return View(userProfile); This obviously won't work
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("InvalidCredentials", "Invalid password. Please try again.");
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

The problem is, how do I pass the view model (`IUserProfile`) to the `Home/Index.cshtml` view because I am not explicitly redirecting him to the home page; it is being done by the `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` method.

I also cannot call a return `View(userProfileViewModel)` after the call to the `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` because if I do, it will, by convention, try to create the view with the name `Index` on the `Login` controller and will try to pass it the `UserProfile` view model, which is wrong and will result in an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the model in your Index action in the Home controller.

Indeed the RedirectFromLoginPage will only send an HTTP status code (302) to the browser telling it to redirect to the new page and then calling the desired action. it is in this action (in your case Index in Home) that you have to pass your view model.

Comment: One way I can think of doing that is putting the userProfile in the session object and then in the HomeController.Index(), loading the profile from the session and passing it to the view.

But if, as you suggest, I need to pass the model into the HttpGet HomeController.Index(Models.UserProfile userProfile), how do I do that?

Comment: @Water Cooler v2 You can get the UserProfile in your Index action by calling User.Identity.Name once logged.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you action should do one thing and one thing only... and not two. You want to use Index as login and as home page. Why don't you separate Login logic from home page logic? When you authenticate a user redirect him/her to Home/Index at that point, and if login fails show Login again. Next, instead of loading user profile during login authentication, do this when you redirect user to their home page (home page being my logic here). Once you reach the page, load their profile and cache it in some way either through session or some other mechanism.

In addition to this, why don't you use `FormsAuthetnication.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe)` instead of `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage`. Once a cookie is created call `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")`. In this action you can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to read the username and pass it to your method to load the profile.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`if (Session["SessionName"].ToString() != "Role")
 {
     return RedirectToAction("UnAuthorised", "Login");
 }`

Use this code in your index page